# How to Build a reliable client side rate limiter without dropping the messages?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, jms

i am calling an external REST API Service from my java code, to prevent overloading that external API I need to ensure that not more than N calls are made to the service S per second. and need to make sure not a single function call is dropped

my function will look like

```
public callXXXAPI(JSONObject message){

formatData(message);

//GET
//REST API
JSONObject response = getDataFromexternalAPI(message);

contineNextProcess(response);
```

}

This method callXXXAPI will be called asynchronously from Kafka consumer.

i need to control the number of times external api getting called.

i.e assume messages getting consumed in high speed in Kafka(1000000 messages per second)  but i need to call the external service 1000 (configurable) times per second. and i do not want to reject the other messages.

i can not solve the problem with Google Guava's Rate Limiter, because when more number of messages getting consumed and more threads will be waiting for the next second and it will get overflowed. should i use any external JMS delay queue to solve this?  any better solution/ architecture for this problem?

Comment: "*N calls are made to the service S per second. and need to make sure not a single function call is dropped*" Basically these are conflicting requirements. If you're throttling and don't want to ever drop a request then you need to queue them. But you can't queue infinitely, so there are cases where you may exceed the size of the queue. If the thing producing the requests is faster than the throttle, you will steadily approach the limit of your queue until your application falls over

Comment: yes if i use in memory queue then queue will be exceed . i need to rate limit but without dropping any data. any suggestion ?

Comment: In-memory or not in-memory. In this universe, we are bounded by finite resources. Memory, disk, whatever. You cannot produce faster than you consume and expect things to work without dropping anything ever. First define how you want to handle the case where the producer consistently exceeds the rate of the throttle, then you finally have some requirements which you can actually implement.

Comment: thanks for the reply..   Its not always we produce lot of messages.. but at some point of time there will be more number of messages will be coming. that particular second we need to limit and handle the remaining messages